# SQL Select and sort on relevance

Tags: sql, select, contains, sql-like

I want to search an table column. and select all rows that contains a string.

I do that on this way:

```
select * from memos where contains (article, '"test*"')
```

The next problem is to order the acticles on relevance. So if a record contains 4 times the word of wordpart 'test' i want it on top and if it contains 3 times the word 'test' i want it below 4. And so order it on how many times a word is in a row.

Comment: Please add a tag indicating the database system you are using

Comment: Godaddy? You're in the wrong place. If you're asking us for code, what you have you tried to solve your problem?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the article is stored as a `varchar()` or `nvarchar()`, then you can do this

```
select *
from memos
where contains (article, '"test*"')
order by len(replace(article, 'test', 'test1')) - len(article) desc;
```

This replaces `test` with a string one character longer, measures the length, and then subtracts the original length.  Voila.  The number of times that `test` occurs.  This should take place only on articles that have the search term.

I'm not sure if SQL Server has something like this built-in to the full text engine.

Comment: +1 correct way of counting occurances of test. Although I would imagine you want the order by to be decending